# Как работает код? JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Реализуйте и экспортируйте по умолчанию функцию, которая принимает на вход два аргумента - количество нулей и количество единиц, и определяет сколько есть способов размещения этих нулей и единиц так, что бы не было двух нулей идущих подряд.

Например, определим все способы размещения двух нулей и двух единиц. Существует шесть возможных способов размещения: 0011, 0101, 0110, 1001, 1010, 1100. В трех случаях содержится два нуля, идущих подряд: 0011, 1001 и 1100. Вычитаем их из общего числа и получаем три возможных способа: 0101, 0110 и 1010. Ответ - 3.

```js
// BEGIN (write your solution here)
const withoutTwoZeros = (a, b) => {
  if (a > b + 1) {
    return 0;
  } else if (a === 0 || b === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  return withoutTwoZeros(a, b - 1) + withoutTwoZeros(a - 1, b - 1);
};

//export default withoutTwoZeros;
// END

console.log(withoutTwoZeros(2,2));
```

В результате задание решено с помощью комбинаторики, а приведенное решение  на ресурсе не понятно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Если число нулей больше чем число единиц хотя бы на 2, то это сделать невозможно:

   ```
   if (a > b + 1) {
     return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Если нужно расставить только нули или только единицы, то способ только один:

   ```
   if (a === 0 || b === 0) {
     return 1;
   }
   ```
3. Если начнём число с `1`, то количество способов для хвоста 
       `withoutTwoZeros(a, b - 1)`.
   Если начнём с `01`, то количество способов для хвоста         `withoutTwoZeros(a - 1, b - 1)`.
   Ставить в начало `00` мы не можем. Итого получается

   ```
   return withoutTwoZeros(a, b - 1) + withoutTwoZeros(a - 1, b - 1);
   ```